# How to move an image on a DIV

Tags: javascript, image, move, drag

Friends,

I want to move an image inserted in a DIV, like a finger on a cellphone.

I'm thinking that I can change the cursor to a "hand", for example.

My example: http://jornalpanorama.hol.es/versao-impressa/

I want to click and hold, drag down or up, to see more of the image.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried so far? not sure what the link is showing? can't see anything relating to the questions

Comment: Try to use `jquery UI` the Drag and Drop functionality

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Draggable Module from jQuery UI:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/